# Rails 4.2.5.1 ActiveRecord : When/Why does one use self[:attr]= in place of write_attribute()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Within an RoR ActiveRecord class what are the pros and cons of using `self[:attribute]=value` as opposed to `write_attribute( :attribute => value )`.  Is it simply a matter of style?  Or is there some deeper reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source on github, you can see that internally it uses the private method `write_attribute_with_type_cast`:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8fdd4bf761b280126e52a212eed187391bdedbb3/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb#L55

This gives you one advantage over just calling `self[:attribute]=value` yourself in that if you're setting `id`, or what you think should be `id`, the method will handle finding the correct attribute name of the primary key for your model.

Finally, through `write_from_user`, rails actually calls `self[:attribute] = value` for you, albeit with different names for things:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8fdd4bf761b280126e52a212eed187391bdedbb3/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb#L38

Beyond the auto-correction of `:id` to `:custom_primary_key` if your model isn't using the standard `id` column as its primary key, there is no functional advantage to using `write_attribute` over `self[:attribute]=value`.